# Clean environment management with Angular2/Ionic/Heroku?

Tags: angular, heroku, ionic-framework, ionic2, environment-variables

In my Python Backend, I have a very clean environment management than I'd like to reproduce in Angular Front-end part.

**The back-end**

I have only 1 setting file, fed by environment variables.
These environments variables are defined in a `.env` file in local, and directly in Heroku interface in staging/prod environments.

env files are not pushed to git repository. This makes it impossible to anyone to access/use production sensitive variables, and make potentiel mistake in environment configuration. Only people which access to Heroku can have access to these sensitive values.

**Ionic/Angular Front-end**

I'd like to create the same behaviour which seems perfect to me.
But from [what I saw](https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be), it seems that the default way consists on creating one .ts file per environment.

Any idea to have a clean environment setup? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum (and standard by angular-cli) without large workarounds is one environment file per Angular app like you saw in that blog/guide. Angular prefers to maintain all of its code base within the root of the project to remain self-contained.

If having one .env per app is too much you could hard code the location of a permanent .env file somewhere in your app, but then the information won't be available during compilation and may cause problems later on...

There are downfalls to this, including potential loss of access to the main .env file. Part of the beauty of Angular is also have *everything* you need for the entire app self-contained. I'd highly recommend you try to shift towards having one environment for every app, even if that requires a copy paste of a global environment file that you use for each one.

Comment: Following this way, I'm screwed with security because my Github repo will contain all sensitive values from prod environment. If I would decide to NOT push the values to Github, then I can not use the same codebase for deploying to Heroku (bye bye auto deployment Github->Heroku-. Seems like I'm screwed anyway ^^

Comment: Pretty much. This is one of the reasons why GitHub forces all free repos to be public. If you spend the $$ you can get a private one, and not have any problems though.

Comment: As an alternative to environment.ts, you can create an external json file with env vars and read it in a singleton service on the app load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at this solution to avoid having your environments hardcoded in the repositories: https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

And also at its first response that introduce a dynamic solution to create the environments files at building time: https://medium.com/@h_martos/amazing-job-sara-you-save-me-a-lot-of-time-thank-you-8703b628e3eb